# compare array elements and print mismatch in unix

Tags: bash

I want to compare the below arrays and print/store only the dissimilar items in another array. can you pls help.

```
eg Array1  for :
20150313 20150324 20150325 20150326 20150330 20150331 20150401 20150402 20150403 20150406 20150407 20150408 20150409 20150410 20150413 20150414 20150415 20150416 20150417 20150418 20150420 20150421 20150422 20150423 20150424 20150427 20150428

eg Array 2 for :
20150313 20150323 20150324 20150325 20150326 20150327 20150330 20150331 20150401 20150402 20150403 20150406 20150407 20150408 20150409 20150410 20150413 20150414 20150415 20150416 20150417 20150418 20150420 20150421 20150422 20150423 20150424 20150427 20150428 20150313 20150323 20150324 20150325 20150326 20150327 20150330 20150331 20150401 20150402 20150403 20150406 20150407 20150408 20150409 20150410 20150413 20150414 20150415 20150416 20150417 20150418 20150420 20150421 20150422 20150423 20150424 20150427 20150428
```

if i try this in bash, it only prints the values in array 1

```
Array3=()
$ for i in "${Array1[@]}"; do
>     skip=
>     for j in "${Array2[@]}"; do
>         [[ $i == $j ]] && { skip=1; break; }
>     done
>     [[ -n $skip ]] || Array3+=("$i")
> done
```

pls assist.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're not trying to compare `a1[i]` to `a2[i]`, cause offsets are possible. An easy way I can think of would be to put them in textual variables with values separated by newlines, and use `diff` to compare them. However, if the order doesn't matter and only the existence of elements matter, i would `sort` - `uniq` first.

Comment: i dont want to do sort -uniq because it gives only unique in both the arrays. i want to print noly the elements in array1 which are not in array 2

Comment: What output are you expecting, post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get `set2 - set1` you can use `grep` with **process substitution**:

```
grep -wFvf <(printf "%s\n" "${arr1[@]}") <(printf "%s\n" "${arr2[@]}")
20150323
20150327
20150323
20150327
```

And to store results in another array:

```
arr3=($(grep -wFvf <(printf "%s\n" "${arr1[@]}") <(printf "%s\n" "${arr2[@]}")))
```

**PS:** To get `set1 - set2` use:

```
grep -wFvf <(printf "%s\n" "${arr2[@]}") <(printf "%s\n" "${arr1[@]}")
```

Comment: it says below error in bash:
 command substitution:syntax error near unexpected token `('
command substitution:`grep -wFvf <(printf "%s\n" "${dates[@]}") <(printf "%s\n" "${volcker_date[@]}"))'

Comment: arr1=20150323 20150327 20150328 20150329
arr2=20150323 20150324
i want to print 20150324 is not available in arr2 and 20150327 20150328  20150329 are not available in arr1.
sorry if i was not clear in first thread

Comment: Are you sure you're using BASH? Run `bash`, enter into bash shell and then try above commands.

Comment: yes in bash, it now printing the below
20150323: command not found
Not all the desimilar dates

Comment: What you've shown in comments is not a BASH array. [See this working demo](http://ideone.com/l7ZFKk) on how to use it.

Comment: below is the bash output now , which prints all the records
20150313
20150316
20150317
20150318
20150319
20150320
20150323
20150324
20150325
20150326
20150327
20150330
20150331
20150401
20150402
20150403
20150406
20150407
20150408
20150409
20150410
20150413
20150414
20150415
20150416
20150417
20150418
20150420
20150421
20150422
20150423
20150424
20150427
20150428

Comment: Script is well tested as you can see from demo. Beyond that I cannot understand data from comments.

Comment: grep -wFvf <(printf "%s\n" "${arr2[@]}") <(printf "%s\n" "${arr1[@]}") is working. many thanks. i got another issue there. let me check it. thanks all guys!!